How to use Torchvison Mixup with a Multilabel Problem?
I want to use MixUp as a data augmentation for a multilabel image classification problem, but it only seems to support labels with the shape (batch_size,). How do I modify this to allow for labels like [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
I tried calling argmax on my labels vector [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0] which gives me a single index. This makes the function work, but it's only doing mixup of a single class.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
